# How to change node type (data, master or client) of an existing node in an elasticsearch cluster without any downtime?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a cluster with several nodes. I want to change the data nodes to master-data nodes dynamically so there is no downtime. What's the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also look at excluding the current data node from hosting shards per https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/allocation-filtering.html
This will move the shards to other data nodes.

Then once the node has no shard (GET _cat/shards?v), you can then restart it after setting node.data: false in elasticsearch.yml

Don't forget to set discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes correctly per https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#split-brain

Comment: node.data: false would need to be node.data: true along with node.master: true since i am change data nodes to master-data nodes

Comment: So if I have a three node cluster, two data nodes and one master-data node, to make it a three master-data node cluster, I first set the quorum setting to 2 (can be done dynamically via rest api), and on one of the data nodes I change config to node.master: true and node.data: true and then dynamically (transiently) disable allocation during restart of data node (to speed restart process up). Rise and repeat on other data node. We should now end up with a cluster of three master-data nodes. Am I missing something please?

Comment: node.master and node.data are true by default so yes set to true or remove/comment out current false settings... If you add master role to data nodes, I would suggest a full cluster restart (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/restart-upgrade.html), add the discovery.zen.minimum_master: 2 node to current master and to the 2 new master-data nodes and start the 3 nodes.
rolling restart risky : new 2 master-eligible would need 2 nodes to elect master while current master is self-elect which basically mean there is a tiny change of split brain

Comment: I have asked in another question about the full cluster restart. can u pls have a look?

Comment: Basically Julien, can u explain more about the risky rolling restart?

Comment: About risk of rolling restart - take one cluster with master1 with discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=1. Now add 2 other master with discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes=2 and assume those 2 nodes do not see master1- in the very unlikely event there is a network split, you now have split brain which can cause data loss. Hence clean way of doing a change from 1 master to 3 master-dedicated involves a full cluster restart

Answer (score 0):

You cant change the role of a node dynamically, you will have to restart it after you have edited the elasticsearch.yml configuration to specify which roles you do or do not want the node to perform.

To avoid outages ensure you have at least one replica set for the affected indices and another available node(recommended) to take on the responsibility you are removing from your to-be dedicated master nodes. The cluster should recover appropriately and with replicas should appear seamlessly.

Once you have your dedicated master nodes you will also want to remove the role from the rest of your cluster nodes, which will also require a restart. Do a rolling restart (ie. one at a time, or equal to the number allotted for failure) but before doing so disable shard allocation. once the cluster is back online re-enable shard allocation. This will prevent unsolicited recoveries from happening.

~Regards

Comment: I wont have any dedicated master nodes. Just master-data nodes, after data nodes are changed to master-data nodes.

Comment: Ah, sorry i reversed the problem. You would just enable master on the data nodes in questions, per others response, and then do a rolling restart. Assuming replicas exist, no downtime.